record_mp3 dependency problem while gradle build in flutter
I executed the flutter project after installing all the required dependencies, did a multiple "flutter clean" and "flutter pub get" but no improvement. I tried changing build.gradle but that was of no use.
please go through this error, i could not find any solution online.
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.czt.mp3recorder:library:1.0.4.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/czt/mp3recorder/library/1.0.4/library-1.0.4.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/czt/mp3recorder/library/1.0.4/library-1.0.4.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/czt/mp3recorder/library/1.0.4/library-1.0.4.pom
- file:/C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/frontend-main/com/czt/mp3recorder/library/1.0.4/library-1.0.4.pom
- https://jitpack.io/com/czt/mp3recorder/library/1.0.4/library-1.0.4.pom
- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/czt/mp3recorder/library/1.0.4/library-1.0.4.pom
Required by:
project :app > project :record_mp3**

I tried changing the dependency, changed the version, tried updating the build.gradle but if was of no use.
I am expecting my project to run without any build and dependency exceptions.

The com.czt.mp3recorder:library:1.0.4 is located in the spring plugins repository, which can't be accessed anymore by anonymous users https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020.
I would recommend making a local build of the project https://github.com/GavinCT/AndroidMP3Recorder, or finding an alternative dependency

Found a savoir record_mp3_plus
It's a fork of the original package. But the com.czt.mp3recorder:library:1.0.4 library has been stored in the project.
